# html5 phone input validation wont submit even tho the pattern is correct

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have some java script to help the user with the phone number and prevent the form from being submitted in till the field has a valid phone number.
How ever even with a valid number it keeps telling me to use the format thats already predetermined. What am I doing worng im going to assume it has something to do with the pattern.

```js
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        // Node/CommonJS
        factory(require('jquery'));
    } else {
        // Browser globals
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {

var ua = navigator.userAgent,
 iPhone = /iphone/i.test(ua),
 chrome = /chrome/i.test(ua),
 android = /android/i.test(ua),
 caretTimeoutId;

$.mask = {
 //Predefined character definitions
 definitions: {
  '9': "[0-9]",
  'a': "[A-Za-z]",
  '*': "[A-Za-z0-9]"
 },
 autoclear: true,
 dataName: "rawMaskFn",
 placeholder: '_'
};

$.fn.extend({
 //Helper Function for Caret positioning
 caret: function(begin, end) {
  var range;

  if (this.length === 0 || this.is(":hidden") || this.get(0) !== document.activeElement) {
   return;
  }

  if (typeof begin == 'number') {
   end = (typeof end === 'number') ? end : begin;
   return this.each(function() {
    if (this.setSelectionRange) {
     this.setSelectionRange(begin, end);
    } else if (this.createTextRange) {
     range = this.createTextRange();
     range.collapse(true);
     range.moveEnd('character', end);
     range.moveStart('character', begin);
     range.select();
    }
   });
  } else {
   if (this[0].setSelectionRange) {
    begin = this[0].selectionStart;
    end = this[0].selectionEnd;
   } else if (document.selection && document.selection.createRange) {
    range = document.selection.createRange();
    begin = 0 - range.duplicate().moveStart('character', -100000);
    end = begin + range.text.length;
   }
   return { begin: begin, end: end };
  }
 },
 unmask: function() {
  return this.trigger("unmask");
 },
 mask: function(mask, settings) {
  var input,
   defs,
   tests,
   partialPosition,
   firstNonMaskPos,
            lastRequiredNonMaskPos,
            len,
            oldVal;

  if (!mask && this.length > 0) {
   input = $(this[0]);
            var fn = input.data($.mask.dataName)
   return fn?fn():undefined;
  }

  settings = $.extend({
   autoclear: $.mask.autoclear,
   placeholder: $.mask.placeholder, // Load default placeholder
   completed: null
  }, settings);


  defs = $.mask.definitions;
  tests = [];
  partialPosition = len = mask.length;
  firstNonMaskPos = null;

  mask = String(mask);

  $.each(mask.split(""), function(i, c) {
   if (c == '?') {
    len--;
    partialPosition = i;
   } else if (defs[c]) {
    tests.push(new RegExp(defs[c]));
    if (firstNonMaskPos === null) {
     firstNonMaskPos = tests.length - 1;
    }
                if(i < partialPosition){
                    lastRequiredNonMaskPos = tests.length - 1;
                }
   } else {
    tests.push(null);
   }
  });

  return this.trigger("unmask").each(function() {
   var input = $(this),
    buffer = $.map(
        mask.split(""),
        function(c, i) {
         if (c != '?') {
          return defs[c] ? getPlaceholder(i) : c;
         }
        }),
    defaultBuffer = buffer.join(''),
    focusText = input.val();

            function tryFireCompleted(){
                if (!settings.completed) {
                    return;
                }

                for (var i = firstNonMaskPos; i <= lastRequiredNonMaskPos; i++) {
                    if (tests[i] && buffer[i] === getPlaceholder(i)) {
                        return;
                    }
                }
                settings.completed.call(input);
            }

            function getPlaceholder(i){
                if(i < settings.placeholder.length)
                    return settings.placeholder.charAt(i);
                return settings.placeholder.charAt(0);
            }

   function seekNext(pos) {
    while (++pos < len && !tests[pos]);
    return pos;
   }

   function seekPrev(pos) {
    while (--pos >= 0 && !tests[pos]);
    return pos;
   }

   function shiftL(begin,end) {
    var i,
     j;

    if (begin<0) {
     return;
    }

    for (i = begin, j = seekNext(end); i < len; i++) {
     if (tests[i]) {
      if (j < len && tests[i].test(buffer[j])) {
       buffer[i] = buffer[j];
       buffer[j] = getPlaceholder(j);
      } else {
       break;
      }

      j = seekNext(j);
     }
    }
    writeBuffer();
    input.caret(Math.max(firstNonMaskPos, begin));
   }

   function shiftR(pos) {
    var i,
     c,
     j,
     t;

    for (i = pos, c = getPlaceholder(pos); i < len; i++) {
     if (tests[i]) {
      j = seekNext(i);
      t = buffer[i];
      buffer[i] = c;
      if (j < len && tests[j].test(t)) {
       c = t;
      } else {
       break;
      }
     }
    }
   }

   function androidInputEvent(e) {
    var curVal = input.val();
    var pos = input.caret();
    if (oldVal && oldVal.length && oldVal.length > curVal.length ) {
     // a deletion or backspace happened
     checkVal(true);
     while (pos.begin > 0 && !tests[pos.begin-1])
      pos.begin--;
     if (pos.begin === 0)
     {
      while (pos.begin < firstNonMaskPos && !tests[pos.begin])
       pos.begin++;
     }
     input.caret(pos.begin,pos.begin);
    } else {
     var pos2 = checkVal(true);
     var lastEnteredValue = curVal.charAt(pos.begin);
     if (pos.begin < len){
      if(!tests[pos.begin]){
       pos.begin++;
       if(tests[pos.begin].test(lastEnteredValue)){
        pos.begin++;
       }
      }else{
       if(tests[pos.begin].test(lastEnteredValue)){
        pos.begin++;
       }
      }
     }
     input.caret(pos.begin,pos.begin);
    }
    tryFireCompleted();
   }


   function blurEvent(e) {
                checkVal();

                if (input.val() != focusText)
                    input.change();
            }

   function keydownEvent(e) {
                if (input.prop("readonly")){
                    return;
                }

    var k = e.which || e.keyCode,
     pos,
     begin,
     end;
                    oldVal = input.val();
    //backspace, delete, and escape get special treatment
    if (k === 8 || k === 46 || (iPhone && k === 127)) {
     pos = input.caret();
     begin = pos.begin;
     end = pos.end;

     if (end - begin === 0) {
      begin=k!==46?seekPrev(begin):(end=seekNext(begin-1));
      end=k===46?seekNext(end):end;
     }
     clearBuffer(begin, end);
     shiftL(begin, end - 1);

     e.preventDefault();
    } else if( k === 13 ) { // enter
     blurEvent.call(this, e);
    } else if (k === 27) { // escape
     input.val(focusText);
     input.caret(0, checkVal());
     e.preventDefault();
    }
   }

   function keypressEvent(e) {
                if (input.prop("readonly")){
                    return;
                }

    var k = e.which || e.keyCode,
     pos = input.caret(),
     p,
     c,
     next;

    if (e.ctrlKey || e.altKey || e.metaKey || k < 32) {//Ignore
     return;
    } else if ( k && k !== 13 ) {
     if (pos.end - pos.begin !== 0){
      clearBuffer(pos.begin, pos.end);
      shiftL(pos.begin, pos.end-1);
     }

     p = seekNext(pos.begin - 1);
     if (p < len) {
      c = String.fromCharCode(k);
      if (tests[p].test(c)) {
       shiftR(p);

       buffer[p] = c;
       writeBuffer();
       next = seekNext(p);

       if(android){
        //Path for CSP Violation on FireFox OS 1.1
        var proxy = function() {
         $.proxy($.fn.caret,input,next)();
        };

        setTimeout(proxy,0);
       }else{
        input.caret(next);
       }
                            if(pos.begin <= lastRequiredNonMaskPos){
                           tryFireCompleted();
                             }
      }
     }
     e.preventDefault();
    }
   }

   function clearBuffer(start, end) {
    var i;
    for (i = start; i < end && i < len; i++) {
     if (tests[i]) {
      buffer[i] = getPlaceholder(i);
     }
    }
   }

   function writeBuffer() { input.val(buffer.join('')); }

   function checkVal(allow) {
    //try to place characters where they belong
    var test = input.val(),
     lastMatch = -1,
     i,
     c,
     pos;

    for (i = 0, pos = 0; i < len; i++) {
     if (tests[i]) {
      buffer[i] = getPlaceholder(i);
      while (pos++ < test.length) {
       c = test.charAt(pos - 1);
       if (tests[i].test(c)) {
        buffer[i] = c;
        lastMatch = i;
        break;
       }
      }
      if (pos > test.length) {
       clearBuffer(i + 1, len);
       break;
      }
     } else {
                        if (buffer[i] === test.charAt(pos)) {
                            pos++;
                        }
                        if( i < partialPosition){
                            lastMatch = i;
                        }
     }
    }
    if (allow) {
     writeBuffer();
    } else if (lastMatch + 1 < partialPosition) {
     if (settings.autoclear || buffer.join('') === defaultBuffer) {
      // Invalid value. Remove it and replace it with the
      // mask, which is the default behavior.
      if(input.val()) input.val("");
      clearBuffer(0, len);
     } else {
      // Invalid value, but we opt to show the value to the
      // user and allow them to correct their mistake.
      writeBuffer();
     }
    } else {
     writeBuffer();
     input.val(input.val().substring(0, lastMatch + 1));
    }
    return (partialPosition ? i : firstNonMaskPos);
   }

   input.data($.mask.dataName,function(){
    return $.map(buffer, function(c, i) {
     return tests[i]&&c!=getPlaceholder(i) ? c : null;
    }).join('');
   });


   input
    .one("unmask", function() {
     input
      .off(".mask")
      .removeData($.mask.dataName);
    })
    .on("focus.mask", function() {
                    if (input.prop("readonly")){
                        return;
                    }

     clearTimeout(caretTimeoutId);
     var pos;

     focusText = input.val();

     pos = checkVal();

     caretTimeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
                        if(input.get(0) !== document.activeElement){
                            return;
                        }
      writeBuffer();
      if (pos == mask.replace("?","").length) {
       input.caret(0, pos);
      } else {
       input.caret(pos);
      }
     }, 10);
    })
    .on("blur.mask", blurEvent)
    .on("keydown.mask", keydownEvent)
    .on("keypress.mask", keypressEvent)
    .on("input.mask paste.mask", function() {
                    if (input.prop("readonly")){
                        return;
                    }

     setTimeout(function() {
      var pos=checkVal(true);
      input.caret(pos);
                        tryFireCompleted();
     }, 0);
    });
                if (chrome && android)
                {
                    input
                        .off('input.mask')
                        .on('input.mask', androidInputEvent);
                }
    checkVal(); //Perform initial check for existing values
  });
 }
});
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
session_start();
$token= md5(uniqid());
$_SESSION['delete_customer_token']= $token;
session_write_close();
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>


<title>index</title>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $.mask.definitions['~'] = "[+-]";
        $("#phone").mask("1 (999) 999-9999");
        

        $("input").blur(function() {
            $("#info").html("Unmasked value: " + $(this).mask());
        }).dblclick(function() {
            $(this).unmask();
        });
    });

</script>



</head>
<body>

<form id="msform"   method="post" action=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="miles" value=""/>


<div id="formwrap">
<div id="ftx1">FIRST NAME</div>
<input type="text" name="fname" class="box" maxlength="40" min="9" max="40" placeholder=""/>
</div>


<div id="formwrap">
<div id="ftx1">LAST NAME</div>
<input type="text" name="lname" class="box" maxlength="40" min="9" max="40" placeholder=""/>
</div>




<div id="formwrap">
<div id="ftx1">BUSINESS NAME:</div>
<input id="busname" name="busname" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="40" value="" placeholder=""/>
</div>




<div id="formwrap">
<div id="ftx1">TYPE OF BUSINESS:*</div>
<input id="bustype" type="bustype" name="bustype" size="" maxLength="64"
          placeholder=""
          title="">
</div>


<div id="formwrap">
<div id="ftx1">EMAIL: *</div>
<input id="email" type="" name="email" size="" maxLength="64"
          placeholder=""
          title="Please provide only a email address" novalidate/>
</div>





 
<div id="formwrap">
<div id="ftx1">PHONE NUMBER: *</div>
<input id="phone" name="phone" class="element text medium" maxlength="" value="" placeholder="PHONE NUMBER" type="tel" pattern="[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}" title="Phone Number Format:1 (614) 000-0000" />
</div> 






<br><br><br><br>



<input id="submit" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" />

<div id="error"></div>


<h2>contact you within 24h. Thank You!</h2>










</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your pattern matches `+91(61)0000-0000` format

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression and field mask combination is incorrect.

`[\+]\d{2}[\(]\d{2}[\)]\d{4}[\-]\d{4}` will never *match* because (a) your mask is configured for North American-style phone numbers (it *will* match phone numbers in the same format as +91(12)3456-7890), and (b) your mask is not configured with a `+` at the beginning of the input.

You may be looking for something similar to the following to validate the field itself:

```
1 \(\d{3}\) \d{3}\-\d{4}
```

<sup>[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/r0UX47/1)</sup>

Comment: Is this why the form will submit even if input is left blank now?

Comment: @jamesgasrdner That'd be because you haven't marked the phone number input field with the HTML5 `required` attribute - the browser won't even attempt to validate it before running the `submit` function.